# How to sort an NSArray on time interval instead of time of day?

Tags: sorting, time, nsstring, nsarray

Is there a way to sort on finish times for a race?  I have an NSArray with a dictionary of NSStrings and one of the values is race finish time as an NSString.  It sorts them all correctly as long as they have the same number of integers, like this: 54.13, 54.32, 54.52... but when one of them is longer, for example: 1:13.42 -- It puts it at the top of the list. How should I sort this so the slower times are at the bottom of the list.  Here is what I currently have:

```
NSSortDescriptor * sortByTime2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"raceTime" ascending:YES];
NSArray * descriptors2 = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortByTime2];
myArray = [myArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors2];
```

thanks,

R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strings "raceTime" are just mere string, they don't represent time. When you want to compare these, you need to convert these string to instances of NSData, then sort. You can use NSSortDescriptor and initialize it with a selector which will do the conversion and return the appropriate order.